# mongodb insert() with look up?

Tags: sql, mongodb, nosql

I'm a newbie when it comes to mongodb so I apologize if this question is simple but I couldn't find an answer anywhere. I have a DB with one collection called genre and each object has an ID and Name , I want to create new collection called Event which has id,Name,genreid. Is it possible to create a event object but instead of passing in the id of a genre to query the id based on the genre name ? I know in SQL it would be

```
 Insert into event(id,name,genreID) values (01,test,(select Id from genre where genre.name ='rock'));
```

Is that possible in Mongo? Cheers in advance

Comment: Are you using mongoose for handling mongoDb? Are you using it in nodejs, or what is the platform?

Comment: Command line in ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Update:

To insert you need to first find the genre _id based on name and then use its _id to create event document.

Try this :

If you are using Mongo Shell, you can do this:

```
var genre = db.genres.findOne({name : "genre_name"});
db.events.insert({
    name : "event_name",
    genreid : genre._id
})
```

Read [Mongodb Shell methods documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/) for more info.

If you are using mongoose and nodejs, you can use this:

```
Genre.findOne({name : "genre_name"}).then(genre => {
    var event = new Event();
    event.genreid = genre._id;
    event.name = "event_name";
    return event.save();
}).then(event=>{
    //event is the newly created event
});
```

Comment: This will work for queries to find all events with a specific genre, but Im looking to insert data into events. but for genreID i want to use a query here instead of just having "01" . something like this . <pre><code>db.getCollection("performer").insertOne({
     "_id" : "0", 
    "name" : "Anderson Paak", 
    "type" : "attraction", 
    "genre_id":db.getCollection("genre").find({ "_name": "Club" },{"_id":1})
}).</code></pre>